# Merge usa and united-states tags

Tags: discussion

The site has both tags: [usa](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa) and [united-states](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states). I can't think of a reason to have both. I think a merger is better because deletion would not prevent the likelihood of it being created again. I favor usa being the duplicate and pointing to united-states as the main tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag mapping and automatic rename exists since September 2011. There was probably some issue with the retagging function for some question, but it seems to have sorted itself out now.

Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

When I got to this question it was 4 hours old. I agreed with the action, and went to implement it, only to find it was already in place!

Not sure if that means one of the other mods beat me to it without mentioning it, or it has been that way long-term.